# Can I reconstruct implant for defect zone for a human patient?

Tags: windows, health

Because my research and learning are continuing…

The point I’m curious about is related to a software; let me try to
explain it step by step.

1. The person’s **CBCT** scan is being taken.
2. Region of interest is **modeled** via CBCT scan.
3. The *defect* area is being reconstructed. The reconstructed region is extracted in stl format.
4. The stl model is being given to the printer program to be sliced.

Does any program in stage-3 do what I want to say? I put a picture at
[image]

Thank you very much in advance

Best regards